# Cannot connect to CRM Dynamics online - OrganizationServiceProxy returns null

Tags: dynamics-crm, office365

I'm trying to connect my console application to CRM but the OrganizationServiceProxy returns null.

I installed the latest version of Microsoft.CrmSdk.CoreTools and added relevant DLLs.

Added the connection string -

`<add name="CRM" connectionString="Url=myOrg.crm4.dynamics.com; Username=myUsername@myOrg.com; Password=myPassword; AuthType=Office365"/>`

But it still returns null as shown below -
[image]

Comment: I can see lot of relate topics in google search..

Comment: Below link will Help. Step by step way to connect CRM

https://arunpotti.wordpress.com/2018/02/03/step-by-step-to-connect-dynamics-365-crm-online-v9-x-using-c-console-application/

Answer (score 0):

Check the properties of `CrmServiceClient`. They will usually point you in the right direction if something is wrong with your connection.

- `IsReady` - should be `true` when working successfully.
- `LastCrmError` and `LastCrmException` - populated if something has gone wrong.